# Transferring data from one pc to another pc without using USB drive

Tags: 14.04, usb, transfer

I have a desktop and a laptop computer and both have UBUNTU 14.04. I have bought the laptop a month ago. All of my data like movies, songs etc stored in the desktop. I want to move all of these data in my laptop without using any USB drive. Is there any way to do it by connecting them together??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to transfer data between ubuntu laptops and desktops without USB.

1) Install SSH in both laptop and desktop.

sudo apt-get install ssh

2)Connect to the network by navigating through network-manager applet on the top panel and choose “connection information”

3) Connect to the target machine and move the folder. (Folder should have read and write permission).

Comment: "Connect to the target machine", how??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have Linux on both machines, with:

- identically named accounts
- sshd running on the laptop
- you are logged on to the desktop
- all the files you want are in your home directory.
- both machines connected via network

To transfer all the data, you can use rsync as mentioned by ApolloLV or just use a tar pipe to transfer your complete home dir:

```
cd ~
tar cf - . |ssh <IP_of_laptop> 'tar xvf -'
```

When you log on to your laptop the next time, you should have all the data. (I would check to make sure before you dump the old machine, though. ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they're both connected to networks (wireless or wired) so just create a shared directory on target machine, map it from source machine and transfer your data.

Cheers,
Silvia

Answer (score 0):

The utility you are looking for is called rsync.

rsync is a file copying program that is able to do so over the internet, that can sync two PCs by just transferring file differences and that is able to continue aborted/failed file copying runs (if run with the correct flag). It is so useful I even use it when copying large amounts of data on one machine!

It uses a SSH connection, so you will have to setup this type of connection on both PCs. SSH is pretty easy to use if you stick with username/password security, but be aware that misconfiguration may pose a big security risk. If you don't plan to use that feature in the future (it really comes in handy when doing remote configuration), I would suggest disabling it afterwards.